# Which has more priority: || or && or ==

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I have this expression:

```
y[i] = ( z[i] == a && b || c )
```

Which of these elements (`&&`, `||`, `==`) have the priority?

Can you please show the order of operations with brackets?

Comment: Quick google search reveals the answer

Comment: fun fact is that this is now literally the highest google search for the query "java and or priority"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First `==`, then `&&`, then `||`.

Your expression will be evaluated as `y[i] = (((z[i] == a) && b) || c)`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 9):

The priority list:

1. ==
2. &&
3. ||

Answer (score 2):

The actual expression is evaluated as

```
y[i] = ( ((z[i] == a) && b) || c )
```

You probably want to look here for more info on operator precedence. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

This would be :

```
y[i] = ((( (z[i]) == a )&& b) || c)
```

ref: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full list of **ALL OPERATORS**:

[Full list of operators in Java](http://prntscr.com/902fsr)

Got it from "Java ist auch eine Insel" = "Java is also an island"