# Expression evaluation inside if loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Why below code is printing inside? Why is the && operator not working?

I know

> if ( (c1 == null || c2 == null) && c3 != null )

will do what I want. But why it's not working without the bracket?

Can someone explain me the rules behind evaluation of expression within if loop?

```
public class HelloWorld
    {
      // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String c1 = null;
        String c2 = null;
        String c3 = null;

        if ( c1 == null || c2 == null && c3 != null ) {
          System.out.println("inside");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is not working without the brackets and works with the brackets because && (and) has higher priority than || (or).

Answer (score 2):

```
c1 == null || c2 == null && c3 != null
```

is equal to

```
c1 == null || (c2 == null && c3 != null)
```

which is

```
true || (true && false)
```

which is

```
true || false
```

which is

```
true
```

Comment: `c2 == null && c3 != null` is not always correct, because either `c2 == null` or `c3 != null` could never be checked (comiler optimize logical operations).

Answer (score 1):

[Java: Which has more priority: || or && or ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583606/java-which-has-more-priority-or-or)

1. ==
2. &&
3. ||

`c1 == null || c2 == null && c3 != null`

1. `c1 == null` -> `true`, `c2 == null` => `true`, `c3 != null` -> false
2. `true || true || false`

To change default priority, you coul duse `(` and `)`, they have hier priority thant `&&` or `||`.

Then actuall y `&&` and `||`, but:

1. `&&` - if at least one (random: left or right) operand is `false`, then other perand are not been checked and result is 'false';
2. `||` - if at least one (random: left or right) operand is `true`, then other perand are not been checked and result is 'true';

This behaviour (optimisation) cannot be changed (I think, it could possible via some compilator options, at least for `C/C++` compiler, it is possible to turn this optimisation off).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add brackets.

```
if ( (c1 == null || c2 == null) && c3 != null ) {
          System.out.println("inside");
}
```

then it will not print the statemnt.