# Can I use associativity on AND and OR on the same time?

Tags: binary, logical-operators, associativity

I don't think the question describes perfectly my problem.

Consider the following:
[image: foo+bar]

How can I simplify this? Does the AND take priority over the OR?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which has more priority: || or && or ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583606/which-has-more-priority-or-or)

Comment: It is making more sense now. However, I'm stuck and I don't know how to semplify the line I included in my question. Do you know where can I look to find answers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dare answering your question because it was part of my studies in electronic on the Boole Algebra.

It should be kinda like this here with 3 :

[image]

I found this [here](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Logique_de_base/Exercices/Alg%C3%A8bre_de_Boole)

Try the same for you. Help yourself ! Answer me back if you need !

Comment: Thanks. I have just found the website and I've been doing the equations. It is clear now. :)